# Undefined at the type level

Tags: haskell, types, undefined, ghc, type-kinds

Often when I'm playing with Haskell code, I stub things out with a type annotation and `undefined`.

```
foo :: String -> Int
foo = undefined
```

Is there a type-level "undefined" that I could use in a similar way?

*(Ideally, in conjunction with a kind annotation)*

```
type Foo :: * -> *
type Foo = Undefined
```

Further thought on the same thread: is there a way for me to stub out typeclass instances for types created this way? An even easier way than the following theoretical way?

```
instance Monad Foo where
  return = undefined
  (>>=) = undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was asked and answered a long time ago; best practices have evolved since.

These days, instead of `undefined`, for stubbing out code you should be using [typed holes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typed-holes), and their type-level analogue, [partial type signatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#partial-type-signatures).

Answer (score 27):

You can use `EmptyDataDecls` to stub out a type, and with `KindSignatures` you can give it a kind:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls, KindSignatures #-}

data Foo :: * -> *
```

You can also stub out the `Monad` instance without warnings with this option to GHC.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-methods #-}

instance Monad Foo
```

And then you don't need to leave any implementation for `return` and `>>=`.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for; it's even more convenient because you don't have to write `Foo = Undefined`! And kind signatures! Awesomesauce.

Comment: I believe it's not the same as a type alias -- when you introduce a new Data, there's no chance that `Foo a = a`. So, it's not the same as the question's code, which may be fine.

Comment: @gatoatigrado : I think the requirement was just a placeholder for a type yet to be written, not a type alias per se, and then this is an appropriate solution. Anyway, glad to help you Dan!